# Setting up some simple formulas and solving them with Z3

Tags: java, z3

I want to set up a simple constraint net, based on three constraints and want it to be solvable with Z3.
I am using an example from automotive:

- Constraint 1: `Price.Car = Price.Engine + Price.Tires + Price.Body`
  whereas each of the prices have a range as defined in below code.
- Constraint 2:

  [image]

  Dependency of speed, power and frontal area. `v`: speed, `P`: power, `A`: frontal area of the car, C<sub>w</sub> air drag coefficient, `rho` density of medium air.
  Side question: How do I express the third root in Z3?
- Constraint 3: `P=ax`

  Dependency between power and price. `P`: power, `a`: proportional constant, `x`: price. Here the result was linearized for simplicity, but it can also be taken from a relational table.

I want the dependencies expressed in Z3 and it being optimised for various variables like for example the maximum speed by using the minimal Price for an engine etc. How can I do that in Z3?
I would appreciate a full code example as I am new to Z3.

I started with the following code, but do not know how to proceed:

```
    IntExpr PriceEngine = ctx.mkIntConst("PriceEngine");
    IntExpr PriceBody = ctx.mkIntConst("PriceBody");
    IntExpr PriceTires = ctx.mkIntConst("PriceTires");

    IntExpr LowerBoundPriceCar = ctx.mkInt(1550);
    IntExpr UpperBoundPriceCar = ctx.mkInt(3200);

    IntExpr LowerBoundPriceEngine = ctx.mkInt(500);
    IntExpr UpperBoundPriceEngine = ctx.mkInt(1000);

    IntExpr LowerBoundPriceBody = ctx.mkInt(1000);
    IntExpr UpperBoundPriceBody = ctx.mkInt(2000);

    IntExpr LowerBoundPriceTires = ctx.mkInt(50);
    IntExpr UpperBoundPriceTires = ctx.mkInt(200);

    //ArithExpr y_plus_one = ctx.mkAdd(y, one);

    //BoolExpr boundPriceCar1 = ctx.mkLt(PriceCar, UpperBoundPriceCar);
    //BoolExpr boundPriceCar2 = ctx.mkGt(PriceCar, LowerBoundPriceCar);

    BoolExpr boundPriceEngine1 = ctx.mkLt(PriceEngine, UpperBoundPriceEngine);
    BoolExpr boundPriceEngine2 = ctx.mkGt(PriceEngine, LowerBoundPriceEngine);

    BoolExpr boundPriceBody1 = ctx.mkLt(PriceBody, UpperBoundPriceBody);
    BoolExpr boundPriceBody2 = ctx.mkGt(PriceBody, LowerBoundPriceBody);

    BoolExpr boundPriceTires1 = ctx.mkLt(PriceTires, UpperBoundPriceTires);
    BoolExpr boundPriceTires2 = ctx.mkGt(PriceTires, LowerBoundPriceTires);

    //BoolExpr bothBoundsPriceCar = ctx.mkAnd(boundPriceCar1, boundPriceCar2);
    BoolExpr bothBoundsPriceEngine = ctx.mkAnd(boundPriceEngine1, boundPriceEngine2);
    BoolExpr bothBoundsPriceBody = ctx.mkAnd(boundPriceBody1, boundPriceBody2);
    BoolExpr bothBoundsPriceTires = ctx.mkAnd(boundPriceTires1, boundPriceTires2);

    ArithExpr PriceCar = ctx.mkAdd(PriceEngine, PriceBody, PriceTires);
    //ArithExpr Speed = ctx.
```

Comment: See for instance the Java examples that come with Z3: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/java/JavaExample.java The function called optimizeExample should fit your case.

Comment: Since you want optimization, you might want to review https://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/optimization As a side note, unless you have to use Java for some other reason, I'd recommend sticking to SMTLib interface (or the Python one), which are both much easier to use.

Comment: @LeventErkok isn't sqrt part of non-linear functionality? is optimization still supported by z3 in this case? I thought it was not.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin I think the cube-root there is red-herring. While I don't understand the details, one can simply take `v_cubed` as a new quantity and get rid of the actual cube-root. There are non-linear terms in there for sure, but if you cast them in terms of `Real`s, I think Z3 still supports them. Lots to experiment with here.

Comment: @LeventErkok is that simple? Non linear terms can be trivially masquerade as linear ones, but it is not obvious to me that linear optimization techniques will actually always work on these problems out of the box.. :-/

Comment: @PatrickTrentin I agree that if the optimization really requires non-linear analysis, I believe z3 optimizer won't stand much of a chance. It is an interesting problem to play around with in any case; to see if the problem can be linearly approximated. The OP already mentions in his Constraint-3 that he's using a linear approximation. Perhaps the other non-linear components can similarly be simplified. Impossible to tell without further domain knowledge.

Comment: @LeventErkok on that I agree

Comment: Here's a slide deck regarding non-linear real optimization by Leonardo: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~gp351/Passmore-Moura-ADDCT-talk-2013.pdf I'm not sure if this ever got implemented though. Would be interesting to find out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165937/discussion-between-patrick-trentin-and-levent-erkok).